# Setting Volley for Nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

What I want to make is a menu list for a cake shop, the menu have **3 categories** and in each category have **different menus**.

So I already have a nested RecyclerView in place, my problem is when I want to connect the RecyclerView with the database. I can make the Volley for the parent RecyclerView easily in the fragment, but its hard to make the StringRequest method for the child RecyclerView because I must set it in **parent RecyclerView's adapter**.

**UPDATE**

I narrowed down my problem, I already know how to make method inside the parent's adapter. Now I have another problem with the child RecyclerView StringRequest.

According to the tutorial that I see [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/android-nested-recycler-view/), to populate each category with different menus I must do it like this :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ParentModel currentItem = parentModelArrayList.get(position);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(cxt, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    holder.childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    holder.childRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    holder.category.setText(currentItem.movieCategory());
    ArrayList<ChildModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // added the first child row
    if (parentModelArrayList.get(position).movieCategory().equals("Category1")) {
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel(R.drawable.themartian,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel(R.drawable.moana,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.mov2,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.blackp,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi2,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.hollywood1,"Movie Name"));
    }

    // added in second child row
    if (parentModelArrayList.get(position).movieCategory().equals("Category2")) {
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel(R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi2,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel(R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi3,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi1,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi4,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi5,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.moviedubbedinhindi6,"Movie Name"));
    }

    // added in third child row
    if (parentModelArrayList.get(position).movieCategory().equals("Category3")) {
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel(R.drawable.hollywood6,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel(R.drawable.hollywood5,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.hollywood4,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.hollywood3,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.hollywood2,"Movie Name"));
        arrayList.add(new ChildModel( R.drawable.hollywood1,"Movie Name"));
    }

    ChildRecyclerViewAdapter childRecyclerViewAdapter = new ChildRecyclerViewAdapter(arrayList,holder.childRecyclerView.getContext());
        holder.childRecyclerView.setAdapter(childRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

It's a success when I tried it myself, but when I try to get the data with Volley I always get a problem, most of the times the problem is that **the StringRequest populate all categories with the same data**. So my question is **How to do the same things using Volley?**

**UPDATE 2**

Today I tried to take the value inside the StringRequest using VolleyCallback interface that I learn from other post, first I want to make it simple by taking only the **name** value and pass it to the onBindViewHolder. Unfortunately it's failed, while the variable inside ViewHolder receive the value correctly, the variable inside onBindViewHolder **returns null**

This is the interface :

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
    void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

This is the method inside ViewHolder class :

```
public void loadChildMenu(int categoryId, final VolleyCallback callback) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Servers.VIEW_TRANSC_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("result");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        name = jObj.getString("name");
                        Log.e("TAG", "Name = " + name);

                        ModelTransaksi modelTransaksi = new ModelTransaksi();
                        modelTransaksi.setId(jObj.getInt("idmenu"));
                        modelTransaksi.setName(jObj.getString("name"));
                        modelTransaksi.setImage(jObj.getString("image"));
                        modelTransaksi.setPrice1(jObj.getInt("price1"));
                        modelTransaksi.setPrice2(jObj.getInt("price2"));
                        modelTransaksi.setSize(!jObj.getString("size").equals("0"));

                        dataChild.add(modelTransaksi);
                    }

                    callback.onSuccess(response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("TAG", "Error : " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("idcat", String.valueOf(categoryId));

                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And this is how I called it inside onBindViewHolder :

```
//Add first child row
    if (dataList.get(position).getIdCategory() == 1) {
        holder.loadChildMenu(1, new VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                name = result;
            }
        });
        Log.e("TAG2", "Name2 = " + name);
        dataChild.add(new ModelTransaksi(name, 1000, 2000, "kacang.png"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of headache, finally I find a way to do it

The key to my solution is **using one StringRequest to populate both parent and child adapter**. First, what I did is get both of the parent and child's data using one php file, This is how I did it :

```
<?php
include_once("../koneksi.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM menu_category";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
$result = array();
$result2 = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
array_push($result, array(
    "idmenu"=>$row['id_menu'],
    "category"=>$row['id_category'],
    "name"=>$row['menu_name'],
    "image"=>$row['menu_image'],
    "size"=>$row['menu_size'],
    "price1"=>$row['price1'],
    "price2"=>$row['price2']
));
}

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
array_push($result2, array(
    "category"=>$row2['id_category'],
    "catname"=>$row2['cat_name'],
));
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result, 'result2'=>$result2));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And then in the StringRequest, get all the data in one method. This is how I did it :

```
private void loadCategory() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Servers.VIEW_TRANSC_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                //Get parent's data
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("result2");
                Log.d("response", String.valueOf(jArray));

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ModelTransaksiParent parentModel = new ModelTransaksiParent();
                    parentModel.setIdCategory(jObj.getInt("category"));
                    parentModel.setTransaksiCategory(jObj.getString("catname"));

                    //Get child data
                    JSONObject childObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray childArray = childObj.getJSONArray("result");
                    ArrayList<ModelTransaksi> childList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j=0; j < childArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject cObj = childArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        if (jObj.getInt("category") == cObj.getInt("category")) {
                            childList.add(new ModelTransaksi(cObj.getString("name"), cObj.getInt("price1"), cObj.getInt("price2"), cObj.getString("image")));
                        }
                    }
                    parentModel.setDataChild(childList);

                    transaksiArrayList.add(parentModel);
                }

                parentAdapter = new TransaksiAdapterParent(transaksiArrayList, getContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(parentAdapter);
                parentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("TAG", "Error : " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

This is probably not the best solution, and I am sure I am gonna change it again if I find a better one, but if the goal just to fill the nested RecyclerView with data then this solution should be good enough.